# How to make a swing component's bounds fixed

Tags: java, swing, resize, layout-manager, jcomponent

I have a `JPanel` to which I have added a few components (checkbox, combo *etc.*). I have noticed that, when the frame is maximized, the bounds of components also move or shift to the right. Then, on restore the components are shifted back to the original position.

On 21 and above inch monitor, the components shift really makes a difference as you can see the components move far right.

We are using customized layout manager which implements `java.awt.LayoutManager2`.  The class content is quiet huge, so will point to the areas which determine the bounds for the components.

```
protected int hMargin = 0;
..
Insets insets = target.getInsets();
Dimension size = target.getSize();

int  x = (size.width - insets.left - insets.right - 15 * hMargin);
```

And from the frame which calls the layout and add the components as shown below:

```
JPanel  pl = new JPanel(new OurLayout(this))
//add the component to panel
pl.add(checkBox);
..
```

At the point where we decide `x`, I want to add a line to prevent the components from shifting when the frame on which the calling *panel* is added is maximized.

Can anyone suggest any ideas on how to achieve this? example code will be well appreciated.

Comment: Have a look into how other layout managers do it. A hint: they use `getPreferredSize()`, `getMinimumSize()` and `getMaximumSize()`.

Comment: why do you roll your own LayoutManager? Flexible, powerful managers are hard to implement, would make sense to check if one of the big three (MigLayout, FormLayout, DesignGridLayout) third-party managers fits your requirements

Comment: Probably not what you want to hear, but why roll your own layout manager, is there anything you need that `SpringLayout` can't do?

Comment: We do have a special specifications of which the custom layout takes care of. Ta!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to `Thomas` and `camickr` for their recommendations, I have achieved a solution using the line of syntaxes below.

```
      size=c.getMinimumSize();
      int dist =(size.width - insets.left - insets.right);
      int move = ((dist > 32) ? 35 : 38);
      x = (dist + move * hMargin);
```

Again thanks to all for the recommendations.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a custom layout manager, then your layout manager should respect the preferred size of the panel. The problem is with your layout management code.

Or for a simple solution add your custom panel to another panel that uses a FlowLayout. Then the preferred size of your custom panel will be respected.